# Open a new window containing a pdf, open browsers print dialog and close the new window

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a multi-page pdf on my server that I want users to be able to print with out them having to open the browsers viewer and click the print button manually.

I know using Javascript's `window.open('http://someurl.pdf');` can be used to open
and display the pdf. Is it possible to immediately run the `Print()` command on that window once this happens so that the browsers print dialog displays? This would then be followed by`window.close()`to close out the newly opened window.

Comment: May be try solution in below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321085/open-pdf-in-new-window-and-call-window-print-in-rails-4