# Open PDF in new window and call window.print() in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf

My objective is for the user to click on a link which right now currently calls a controller action and returns

`send_data(label.pdf_text, type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline')`

This displays the pdf in its own window.

What I want to do is when the link_to is pressed, it calls the controller action to open up a dummy html file which automatically calls in javascript,

`window.print();`

So in this case, link is pressed and opens up the pdf in a new window/tab and immediately calls the window.print(); javascript function to show a print preview.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add this js to your html file witch contains pdf:

```
<script>
  function ready() {
    window.print();
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready)
</script>
```

**ready** function will be launch and call **window.print();** after your html page is load

Comment: Correct, I just need to render the pdf in the html page. Not sure how.